# Requests Dies Or Responded later On Socket Closed Erro

Tags: sockets, amazon-ec2

I have one AWS EC2 instance , I did some requests from Jmeter , and as I had users High so I got Socket Closed Error. But later after 2-3 Hours I saw new EC2 instance becaus autoscaling was true. Still not figured , just Wandering What happens the Socket Closed Exception , does the requests gets into a Queue and processed later , then thus so many requests so AWS created a new instance to process the Queue requests OR the requests dies at the Socket ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you tried a load test during which you got some connection errors. If so then no, in general failed connects will not be retried. It entirely depends on the protocol and applications being used, though.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for replying ...